# 95% confidence interval error bars

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm doing a research and trying to calculate and put error bars (95% confidence) on my excel chart. However, I have trouble understanding what exactly do I have to calculate in order to present my data correctly.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Where I'm having trouble is which data should I use when calculating the interval? Should I use only the control and treatment groups and calculate the interval between them?
What I tried was calculating **standard error** separetly for each group and each age group.

So, 
**SE for 30-45 age group:**

- control: 0.0168=1.68%
- treatment: 0.0639=6.39%
- all: 0.0213=2.13%

I then multiplied **SE** with **1.96** to get he values, however, the lower limit goes to the negative.

My initial thinking was that I should calculate standard errors for each groups separately, which would give different error bars. Would this be a correct way of doing it or are those type of analysis done differently?

Thank you

edit: what my data actually represents is the % of people suffering from a certain disease. So the numbers are % of people with the disease in group one and group two. I can provide exact numbers if that's needed. What I wanted to estimate is to see how many (%) people are affected in certain age groups and how groups 1 and 2 compare to each other.

Comment: If you assume normal distribution there is no reason why values should not be negative since its support is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$... Please add more details on what is your data and what do you want to estimate.

Comment: Thank you. I've read about this, yes, but my initial concern was if my calculation should be done for each group/category separately or there should be only on confidence interval +- for all of them. I also edited the post.